# How can I load an XML document using TBXML's methods from given url?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode4, tbxml

I'm trying to use TBXML's method:

```
+ (id)tbxmlWithURL:(NSURL*)aURL success:(TBXMLSuccessBlock)successBlock failure:(TBXMLFailureBlock)failureBlock;
```

from the TBXML+HTML.h
But I can't find any information about `TBXMLSuccessBlock` and `TBXMLFailureBlock`. Even on official tutorials you can only see:

```
TBXML * tbxml = [[TBXML tbxmlWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.w3schools.com/XML/note.xml"]] retain];
```

But when I try it out, Xcode tells me that there is no such class method. 
BTW, I'm using ARC (so i don't write `retain`).

So the question is: how can I load an XML document using TBXML's methods from given url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TBXMLSuccessBlock` and `TBXMLFailureBlock` are used as an efficient way for implementing conditions for successful and unsuccessful retrieval of the XML data from the given URL. Look at Apple's [Blocks programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/00_Introduction.html) for more in-depth information about Objective-C blocks.

If you just want some example code on how to use it, here it is (using the latest version of TBXML):

```
TBXMLSuccessBlock s = ^(TBXML *tbxml) {
    NSLog(@"yay");
    // Do something with TBXML object "tbxml
    // ...
    // An example - print the name of an element
    TBXMLElement *e = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"head" parentElement:tbxml.rootXMLElement];
    NSString *a = [TBXML elementName:e];
    NSLog(@"%@",a);
};

TBXMLFailureBlock f = ^(TBXML *tbxml, NSError *error) {
    // Do something to recover from the failure here
    // ....
    NSLog(@"nay");
};

[TBXML newTBXMLWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.co.nz"]
                              success: s
                              failure: f];
```

When you execute this code, TBXMLSuccessBlock should execute if you have access to the following URL. If you can't reach the website, the TBXMLFailureBlock will execute.

As a side note, if a library you are using is non-ARC (assuming the library is source code and not a static or dynamic library ) and you are trying to integrate it into ARC-ified source, you can do this under Xcode by going to your xcodeproj file -> Build Phases -> Compile sources and for each .m file that does not use ARC, enter the compiler flag `-fno-objc-arc` which will tell the compiler not to compile it with ARC.

Comment: For some reason under SDK 5 with ARC, the initwithurl documented everywhere did not work for me. Either throwing method unknown or not executing the blocks. Your code here made it work for me.